# Cypress cy.origin() & Google sign in not working

Tags: cypress, google-signin, auth0

I'm trying to login to our site which uses Auth0 and Google Sign in but I'm having issues with cy.origin it's behaving different in each browser, none of which is letting me log in. This is my test:

```
import { loginPage } from '../../page-objects/login-page'

describe('Login Tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    loginPage.visit()
  })

  it('GoogleLogin', () => {
    // Click google sign in button - On My Base URL
    cy.get("a[data-testid='googleSignInButton']").click()


    // I'm now on an Auth0 Page where I click the Google Sign In Button
    cy.get("a[class='auth0-lock-social-button auth0-lock-social-big-button']").click()

    // Now I am on the accounts.google.com domain 
    cy.origin('https://accounts.google.com', () => {

      // enter email on accounts.google.com
      cy.get("input[type='email']").type('myemail@gmail.com')

      // click next button seen on accounts.google.com page
      cy.get(
        "button[class='VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc LQeN7 qIypjc TrZEUc lw1w4b']",
      ).click()
    })
  })
})
```

The issues I'm seeing are:

- In Chrome once I get to accounts.google.com the test times out with "Timed out after waiting 60000ms for your remote page to load on origin(s)"
- In Firefox the test times out with the same error as on Chrome but on the Auth0 page instead of accounts.goole.com
- In Electron when I click the Google Sign in button on Auth0 I'm taken to accounts.google.com but a message is displayed "403. That’s an error. We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know."
- In Edge I can get to accounts.google.com and enter "myemail@gmail.com" and click the next button but then I see a message "This browser or app may not be secure.
  Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in." with a Try again button.

Four browsers are all reacting differently and not one is letting me actually login, can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried looking at Cypress social logins? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-social-logins

Comment: I haven't but it says "This plugin doesn't work well in a CI environment" so it wouldn't be fit for my purpose.

Comment: If you read the statement **beyond the bold text** it says that the problem is Google fraud detection, not the plugin itself.